# How to add new columns in the existing file in unix?

Tags: unix, field, string-concatenation

I want to add two new columns in my file:
Existing file has 2 columns:

```
ABCD,1234
QWER,3333
TTYY,2323
YYPP,1789
```

New file : **2 columns(fields) to be added.** 
  --> 3rd field should have same value as 1st field.
  --> 4th filed  will always have same value 'XXXX'

```
ABCD,1234,ABCD,XXXX
QWER,3333,QWER,XXXX
TTYY,2323,TTYY,XXXX
YYPP,1789,YYPP,XXXX
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an internal shell loop:

```
while IFS=, read first second; do
  echo "$first,$second,$first,XXXX"
done <your_file.dat >new_file.dat
```

but using `awk` is in most cases faster:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $1,$2,$1,"XXXX"}' your_file.dat >new_file.dat
```

- `-F,` tells `awk` that the *input* field separator is `,`
- `-vOFS=,` tells `awk` that the *output* field separator is `,`